# JFrame Components In Wrong Place After Programmatical Resize

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am currently working on an audioplayer in Java, and it's got several components. It's got a menu, a vertical volumeslider, a horizontal timeslider, several JButtons and a JMenu. When the program is launched (I launch it without the default JFrame border) in a resolution of about 640x360 all the components are in the right place, and I can resize it while the frame is opened to about 380x280 with which all the components are still in the right place. However, when I launch the application immediatly with a 380x280 resolution all the components are in the wrong place, and several components have not been loaded.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and perhaps how I can solve it so that I can launch it in a resolution of 380x280 upon startup?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks for contributing nothing at all.

Comment: What do you mean? I offered a suggestion and contributed a close vote. Now I'll also give you a down vote, just because you're *special.*

Answer (score 0):

Start the program with 640x360, the JFrame is not visible, after a second set the size to 380x280 and then show the JFrame. You can also try the JFrame.pack() Methods :)